# twitter typeahead.js: can't invoke click() handler on link within suggestion

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I am using [Twitter Typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) and am unable to get a JQuery click() handler invoked when a target anchor tag is part of a suggestion template. Please see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dukehoops/gYUQL/) demo'ing the problem; excerpt below:

```
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function (evt) {
    console.log("clicked; currentVal=" + $(this).data('currentVal'));
    return false; //stop click propagation
});

$('#search').typeahead({
    name: 'foo',
    local: ['alpha', 'alfalfa', 'bravo', 'charlie'],
    engine: Hogan,
    template: '<p>{{value}} <a href="#" class="remove" data-current-val="{{value}}">Remove</a></p>'
});
```

How can I get my click handler invoked (before typeahead's)? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a [known bug](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/118) which should get fixed in v0.10.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @jharding - and Typeahead. Seems like 0.10.0 is being cut without a fix for the above. Latter minor release, perhaps?

Comment: Last I checked, this was currently fixed in the 0.10.0 branch.

Comment: Hi, is there a workaround while we're waiting on a new release? Failing that, is there an ETA on 0.10?

Comment: Did you guys get a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can invoke your click handler by binding on it to `typeahead:selected`.

```
$('#search').typeahead({
    name: 'foo',
    local: ['alpha', 'alfalfa', 'bravo', 'charlie'],
    engine: Hogan,
    template: '<p>{{value}} <a href="#" class="remove" data-current-val="{{value}}">Remove</a></p>'
}).on('typeahead:selected', function(object, data) {
    //your code goes here.
})
```